# How To Get The Value Single Time From A Column at Sql Table

Tags: sql, time

I have table named usertable and structure is

```
     id     Name        Year
   ==========================
     1       a          2010
  ____________________________
     2       b          2008
  ____________________________
     3       c          2010
  ____________________________
     4       d          2007
  ____________________________
     5       e          2008
```

Now I want the Output result like this

```
    Year
 ==========
    2010
____________
    2008
____________
    2007
```

I don't know the SQL query .

So please help me.

Every Ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but if you're looking for the years that are in the table in descending order, then you could use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year FROM usertable ORDER BY year DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Year]
FROM   myTable
ORDER BY [Year] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Year DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY Year DESC
```

if you wan't to be more than tape monkey here's a brilliant hands on source http://sqlzoo.net/0.htm